# \usepackage{syntax} causes an undefined control sequence error?

Tags: errors, packages

My document is using the following packages:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{setspace}
```

At the moment it complies fine, but when I include `\usepackage{syntax}` I get the following error:

```
[13]
! Undefined control sequence.
\filename@simple ...#2\\}\fi \edef \filename@base 
                                                  {#1}
l.306 ...th=\linewidth]{images/user_interface.png}

?
```

and getting rid of the `syntax` package causes it to run just fine again.

EDIT: here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{syntax}
\doublespacing

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images/user_interface.png}
        \caption{User Interface}
        \label{fig:user_interface}
    \end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Seems to be tied to the `_`s in the arguments of `\includegraphics` and `\label`.

Comment: @DaiBowen I tried escaping those with \ and got a new error: `!Missing number, treated as zero`

Comment: `\usepackage[nounderscore]{syntax}`

Comment: @roncook as I understand, `syntax` makes `_` an active character, calling a macro for typesetting underscores - this doesn't work well when the underscore is used in things like label or file names as that's not immediately typeset.  If you pass the `nounderscore` option to the Syntax package then it won't make underscore active, but you'll need to use `\_` to get underscores typeset as the Syntax package

Comment: [nounderscore] solved it! Thanks @dai and egreg